# What does "Up with, down without" mean?

Tags: meaning

Dougie explains why they call the Arctic the Arctic and the Antarctic the Antarctic:

> Dougie: "Arktos" means "bear" in Greek. "Ant" means "without." Hence,
> ant arktos, "without bears."
>
> Patrick: **Up with, down without**. Good news for ice cubes, bad news  for
> polar bears.

What does "Up with, down without" mean?

Comment: In the context, it means the Arctic ("up"), has bears, and the Antarctic ("down"), has no bears. It's not a standard English sentence, and without the context, it would sound like bad grammar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This whole exchange is a joke.  I hope you realise that "antarctic" doesn't mean "without bears".

However it is true that there are no polar bears in the Antarctic... so "*Up* (or North) is *with* bears, and  *down* (or South) is *without* bears.

Thus "Up with, down without"

(Arctic is from Greek Arktos=bear, but it refers to the constellations of the greater and lesser bear that are in the Northern sky.  "Anti" means opposite and Antarctic is the region opposite the Arctic)

Comment: Not everybody knows that it is conventional to present maps, globes, etc, with North at the top. My boss in the 1990s didn't.